# Hiding the Hamburger while in shell using template10

Tags: win-universal-app, hamburger-menu, template10

Sorry if my query's a bit noobish, a uwp beginner here.

I'm trying to morph the hamburger template from template10 and an existing project of mine. Basically, I'd like to have a certain page with the hamburger menu being invisible, and display my own navigation buttons on the page (an intro page). Upon navigation away to any other page the menu will be visible again.

I tried changing Hamburger's visibility state as an experiment, but it seems to be affecting the content as well. Is what I'm talking about possible with this control and I'm missing something obvious? Or I'd have to manage shell usage in app.xaml and load my intro page without the shell?

Many thanks for the creation of the t10 btw (Jerry, Daren and everyone else), me being confused in this thing doesn't at all diminish my appreciation

Comment: can you insert your xaml code so that anyone who want to help can easily know where's the problem.

Comment: btw, for posterity's sake- I've found https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/170 which is very similar to my question

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options for you here. IsPaneOpen will only work for you depending on the DisplayMode you choose. But if I were to guess, it's HamburgerMenu,.IsFullScreen that you are really wanting to use here.

Comment: Hey Jerry, thanks for the reply. I had this bright idea that I could check the HamburgerMenu's implementation on t10's git (all praise open source!) and found this property as well. I'll test soonish and update here, but looks to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I tried, but it wont hide the hamburger icon

            <Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu"  
                                HamburgerButtonVisibility="Collapsed" 
                                IsEnabled="False" 
                                Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                IsFullScreen="False">
            </Controls:HamburgerMenu>

Answer (score 1):

You can change the SplitView mode to Inline and set IsPaneOpen to false. That will hide the Pane.